# Remove tokens from Hugging Face tokenizer and save

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, vocabulary, pruning

In the current implementation, what is the recommended way for removing tokens from a any Hugging Face `PreTrainedTokenizer`? Simply creating a new vocabulary.txt and loading it with `from_pretrained` is [deprecated](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/cf11493dce0a1d22446efe0d6c4ade02fd928e50/src/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py#L1620) and does not scale to all tokenizers. I know that there are specific methods for *adding* tokens but I have not found ones that allow for the deletion of any original token.

So I would like to be able to remove a given set of tokens from any tokenizer's vocabulary and then save this updated tokenizer with `save_pretrained`.